# Grid Bag Layout will not fill button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have this code

```
//Create the single player panel
    singlePlayerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(); 
    gbc.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);
    JLabel STypeOfGameLabel = new JLabel("Type Of Game:");
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(STypeOfGameLabel,gbc);
    JComboBox STypeOfGameCombobox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"Normal (12*2 cards)", "Double (24*2 cards)"});
    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(STypeOfGameCombobox,gbc);
    JCheckBox SShowRandomly = new JCheckBox("Show Randomly");
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(SShowRandomly,gbc);
    JCheckBox SSwap = new JCheckBox("Swap");
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=3;
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(SSwap,gbc);
    JCheckBox SCertainOrder = new JCheckBox("CertainOrder");
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=4;
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(SCertainOrder,gbc);
    JButton SPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=5;
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    gbc.gridheight=3;//DOESN'T WORK
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(SPlay,gbc);
    JButton SBack = new JButton("Back");
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=8;
    gbc.gridheight=3;
    singlePlayerPanel.add(SBack,gbc);
```

the SPlay button does not get bigger.
[image: screenshot]

and i have no idea what am i doing wrong. If i do it on any checkbox it works, but on this button it doesn't.

P.S Java newbie

Comment: The buttons fill the grid. You only have two columns so the button fills the two columns. I'm not sure what you want to happen. If you expect the button to fill the width of the entire frame, then take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The demo shows you how to have components fill the entire space. So download the demo a play with it.

Comment: Thank you! answered my question :)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed was to put

```
gbc.ivory=50;
```

instead of

```
gbc.gridheight=3;
```

to make the component tall.

[image]